# ASP.NET MVC 5 Merging ApplicationUser with DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to integrate ASP Identity into my own DbContext but I'm having no luck with it. What I'm trying to achieve is that each Deal that is posted, a user will be assigned to it.

DbContext:

```
public class ShareDealsContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{    
    public ShareDealsContext() : base("name=ShareDealsContext")
    {
    }

    // Other DbSets
    public DbSet<Deals> Deals { get; set; }
}
```

Deals Model:

```
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public virtual string UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

Identity Models:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Deals> Deals { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultContext", throwIfV1Schema: false) { }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

I've tried replacing "DefaultContext" to "ShareDealsContext" inside ApplicationDbContext but still does not work. I'm wanting to remove DefaultContext completely and just use my own ShareDealsContext. Any ideas on what I am missing out on? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Could you replace DefaultContext with connection string name from web.config?

```
public ApplicationDbContext() : base("CONNECTION_STRING_NAME", throwIfV1Schema: false)
```

For example,

[image]

Web.config

[image]